# dotnet publish doesn´t publish correct appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, publish, dotnet-cli

When I issue the following command in the command line:

`dotnet publish -o "./../output" -c Release`

The `dotnetcli` publishes the project correctly. However, it does not copy the `appsettings.Production.json` file, only the `appsettings.json`.

Why is this? I have googled around and read the official core docs, but haven't found how the correct environment `appsettings.json` is supposed to end up in the publish output.

Should I copy `appsettings.Production.json` manually to the published folder?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54216774/10685590) for a possible solution of environment specific appsettings.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**Update:**
[For current (new) .csproj format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj) the  `CopyToPublishDirectory` attribute should be used. It determines whether to copy the file to the publish directory and can have one of the following value:

- Always,
- PreserveNewest
- Never

So add next section into your `.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="appsettings.Production.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Look into [@nover answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603846/2833802) and SO [Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish/42713770#42713770) for more information about file's control during publishing.

---

"In your `project.json` file you have the section `publishOptions` with subsection `include`, where you already have some files like "appsettings.json":

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "appsettings.json",
    "hosting.json",
    "project.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},
```

You should add `"appsettings.Production.json"` into this array.

**Updates based on comments**:

- Keep in mind, that all the `appsettings.*.json` files like `appsettings.development.json`, `appsettings.staging.json` and `appsettings.production.json` will always end up in all environments. You cannot simply handle this using `project.json`, as it does not support any condition rules. This will be changed in future, when `project.json` will be [replaced back](http://ivanz.com/2016/05/17/farewell-project-json-hello-msbuild-and-csproj) to `msbuild` and `.csproj`. If this is critical for your app, consider to use another configuration store, like Environment Variable, database, etc.
- Note, that order is important, as determine which settings will be applied if they exist in multiple locations. From [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html):

  > The order in which configuration sources are specified is important, as this establishes the precedence with which settings will be applied if they exist in multiple locations. In the example below, if the same setting exists in both appsettings.json and in an environment variable, the setting from the environment variable will be the one that is used. The last configuration source specified “wins” if a setting exists in more than one location. The ASP.NET team recommends specifying environment variables last, so that the local environment can override anything set in deployed configuration files.

Comment: Why do you need `project.json` to be published at all?

Comment: But it doesn't merge a setting based on publish profile? It always reads the key which is in appsettings.json, not appsetting.release.json.

Comment: In my case, settings from the publish profile actually get merged with my appsettings.Production.json @BarbarosAlp

Comment: does that mean all the appsettings files like `appsettings.development.json`, `appsettings.staging.json` and `appsettings.production.json` will always endup in all the environment?

Comment: project.json is phased out, not appsettings.json !

Comment: The  CopyToPublishDirectory attribute in the .csproj file doesn't copy anything! So this doesn't work.

Comment: @ygoe it works for me with `dotnet publish`... You may create a SO question and describe your problem

Answer (score 17):

In your `project.json` there is a section `publishOptions`. This lists all the files and folders that will be included when you publish. You will need to update yours to look something like this

```json
{
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
}
```

You can also use globbing patterns, so you should find this works too (I haven't tested this one)

```json
{
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings*.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 17):

For the new `csproj` project format you have to add a new `ItemGroup` with the content

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
  <Content Include="appsettings.Production.json">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

In case you have multiple `appsettings.{env}.json` files simply repeat the `Content` tag inside the same `ItemGroup` and all your settings files will end up in the publish folder.

As mentioned in the comments an even cleaner solution is to use a wildcard include:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="appsettings*json">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

And all your `appsettings` files will be published!

Comment: You also can take advantage of wildcards, and use the single node with `Include="appsettings*json"`. You can do it manually.

Comment: nice one @stukselbax - incorporated your feedback in my response

Comment: Doesn't work. The build error says these files are already defined elsewhere. Seems the default behaviour can't be overwritten.

Comment: @ygoe yes this is something new in the dotnet toolchain - the build tools are considering them as implicitly included.

Answer (score 10):

**After Visual Studio 2017 15.3**

Edit the .csproj file to manually exclude files/folder from being published

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

ref: https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/273/fixing-the-duplicate-content-error-after-upgrading-visual-studio-2017

[original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671283/810850)

Answer (score 6):

Discovered a three-step build in Visual Studio approach for publishing **environment-specific** appsetting files (Windows, PowerShell).

- appsettings.json
- appsettings.Development.json
- appsettings.Staging.json
- appsettings.Production.json

This approach will publish

- appsettings.json and
- appsettings.$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT).json.

Step 1. Update csproj:

```
  <!-- App Settings -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
    <Content Remove="appsettings.*.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup> 
    <Content Include="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    <Content Include="appsettings.$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT).json" DependentUpon="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Step 2. Set an environment variable in PowerShell:

```
  # Read
  [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "User")
  # Output: empty string if not set or 'Staging' in my case
  # Set environment variable "User" or "Machine" level
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Staging", "User")
```

Step 3. Then close and reopen Visual Studio solution to enable Visual Studio to see the environment variable and reload project structure accordingly.

- Now appsettings.json is a parent and appsettings.Staging.json is a nested file.
- If you set another environment (for example "Production") and then close and  Visual Studio and reopen your  solution, then you will appsettings.json as a parent and appsettings.Production.json as a nested file.

[image]

**Final step**. Run publishing.

[image]

**Note:** **publishing profile** environment variables **do not affect** publishing configuration. This approach uses PowerShell to set an environment variable and enables environment-specific publishing. Please see [link](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/) for more details on environment variables.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I am using VS 2022, but this works for 2019 as well.  I was having the same issue with my debug/release configurations.  I wanted only to publish appsettings.json during a release publish, but the appsetting.Development.json was always copied as well.  With a bit of searching, I found the choose/when option.

`<Choose><When Condition=""></When></Choose>`

With two When sections, one for Debug and one for Release I was able to accomplish this beautifully.

```
<Choose>
        <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
            <ItemGroup>
                <Content Include="appsettings.Development.json">
                    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
                    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
                </Content>
            </ItemGroup>
        </When>
        <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
            <ItemGroup>
                <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
            </ItemGroup>
        </When>
    </Choose>
```

I hope this helps.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thanks! This works for me for I only need to remove "appsettings.Development.json" when the build configuration is "Release" so that the customers won't see my connection string for DEV. I only added the second "When" block.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2019 (Version 16.4.1) has option to publish only the `appsettings.json` on right click on the file:

[image: publish-json]

It will take your connection from the publish profile.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not appsettings*.json are included is also a behavior that is part of the used sdk. Defined in the csproj file.
[Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web](https://github.com/dotnet/websdk/blob/c782b82decd04b49771814064a8f9fe3a07ed341/src/ProjectSystem/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props#L30-L32) copies *.json and *.config by default. Microsoft.NET.Sdk does not.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you don't need to manually modify the project file to add in the items. Just set the "Build Action" to "Content" for these items in file properties. They get copied to the build output AND the publish folder. They're also included in the Application Files folder with the .deploy extension if you're publishing for ClickOnce.

[image]