# Is it possible to publish only certain appsettings.json in .NetCore application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have 4 appsettings.json in my .NetCore application:

- appsettings.json
- appsettings.Development.json
- appsettings.Test.json
- appsettings.Production.json

All of appsettings has **Do not copy** property, but I notice when publishing the application, all of appsettings files are copied over to publish folder. 
For example, *appsettings.Production.json* is copied to publish folder even I am publishing using *Test* environment.

It doesn't hurt but I want to know whether is it possible to copy just *appsettings.json* and *appsettings.Test.json* when publishing using *Test* environment?

Comment: It is possible to delete files before and after publishing in visual studio publish profile. You can create various publish profiles, each one deleting your specified appsettings after publishing.

Comment: How did you specify the Test environemnt while publishing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to publish environment specific appsettings in .Net core app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256057/how-to-publish-environment-specific-appsettings-in-net-core-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, the trick is to use `<Content Remove="">` for appsettings.json.

I updated my .csproj to use [conditional constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2017) to switch between different environments. Here is what it looks like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Default behaviour here -->
  <None Update="other_files">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup> 
<Choose>
  <When Condition=" '$(EnvironmentName)'=='Test' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
      <Content Remove="appsettings.Production.json" />

      <!-- Other files you want to update in the scope of Debug -->  
      <None Update="other_files">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
</Choose>
```

The folder now does not contain `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json` when I run publish using `Test` environment.

Answer (score 2):

While publishing, we could specify `Configuration`. To implement your requirement, you could define different configurations by `Configuration Manager`.

1. Click Debug or Release Dropdown ->Configuration Manager -> New Active solution configuration for `Development`, `Test` and etc like `DevelopmentPublish` and `TestPublish`
2. Modify project.csproj

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
       <Configurations>Debug;Release;DevelopmentPublish</Configurations>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <Target Name="DevelopmentPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish" Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='DevelopmentPublish'">
       <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)$(publishUrl)appsettings.Development.json" />
   </Target>
   <Target Name="TestPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish" Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='TestPublish'">
       <Message Text="TestPublish"></Message>
       <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)$(publishUrl)appsettings.Test.json" />
   </Target>
   </Project>
   ```
3. While publishing, choose the expected configuration for publish like `TestPublish` for test publish process.

Comment: I just created different publishing profiles for each environment and added the "delete target" directly to each with the specific files to remove for that environment.  Thanks for the idea.  Works well!