# .Net-Core IdentityServer - Type not supported

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core, debian, identityserver4

I am trying to deploy my .net core 3.1 project to debian using nginx runtime-dependent. I developed it on Windows, everything works fine while debugging. However, on production I am stuck with a 502 because of this error;

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Type '' is not supported.
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureClients.GetClients()+MoveNext()
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureClients.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
  at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
  at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
  at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
  at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
  at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
```

I tried to add signing credential to identityServer like this;

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("/etc/myapp/IdentityServerCertificate.pfx");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes, "PWD");
identityServer.AddSigningCredential(cert);
```

Also I added a key to IdentityServer in appsettings.json;

```
      "IdentityServer": {
        "Clients": {
            "MyClient": {
                "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
            },
            "Key": {
                "Type": "File",
                 "FilePath": "/etc/myapp/IdentityServerCertificate.pfx",
                "Password": "PWD"
                }
        },
```

But it didn't work. This seems to be a problem related to GetClients() method rather than the certificate. I also tried configuring clients through code. Any other idea? Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the GetClients method content? It seems there is something wrong there.

Comment: Please see the github link below @nahidf shared.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is cause of the way you configured list of clients on appsettings.json. The profile property for client should be one of items listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#application-profiles

Here is where error is raised https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Configuration/ConfigureClients.cs#L48

Comment: Yes but I still cannot figure out why. I have updated appsettings.json above to include clients details. It looks simple but does not work. I also tried configuring clients through code.

Comment: @Tany3450 what config do you use to publish to prod? for example if you use `prod` config to publish you need to have `appsettings.Prod.json`. check here for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#appsettingsjson  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environments

Comment: It reads appsettings.json so I think it is fine. I use this command; dotnet publish --configuration Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained false

Comment: @Tany3450 my question is more about if the proper appsettings is copied & read once deployed, because if things works locally but not working on prod means sth is off during deployment, checkout this answer to make sure u have deployment setup properly https://stackoverflow.com/a/54216774/3486567

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed because of key being defined under Clients rather than IdentityServer.