# appsettings.json not getting copied to build package

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuild-task

I am using TFS 2018 on-prem to build by ASP.Net Core application. I use the Visual Studio Build task (Version 1.*) with no additional MSBuild arguments. That is I just build my project by pointing to the `project.sln` file.

The issue is I don't get my `appsetting.*.json` in my build results so that I can do transformations on it. Both on build agent and my result zip file do not have the JSON file.

In my csproj, I do have the following:

```
<ItemGroup> <Content Update="appsettings.json">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> </Content>  
   ... 
</ItemGroup>
```

When I build through VS2017, I do get my appsettings.json files copied to the bin folders. If I publish from my VS2017, I get the appsettings.json files in my published folder.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the TFS to build tasks to copy my JSON files?

Comment: You should increase the verbosity of the build to diagnostic and see why that file is not getting copied.

Answer (score 2):

By changing the appsetting.json to be an Embedded resource I solved my problem.

See this for the full answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49778593/375114

Comment: I can confirm this. First I had the Build Action of appsettings.json defined as Content. The json file was not fetched by TFS during a build. First I solved this by choosing Clean Sources in Get sources, but this is not a real solution. With Build Action = Embedded Resource appsettings.json is always properly updated in a TFS build.