# Wrong appsettings.json being copied to debug folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

My unit test project has its own appsettings.json file.

In the same solution, I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI Project with an appsettings.json file.

I also have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor project that has an appsettings.json file.

When I run my unit tests, the appsettings.json file from the WebAPI project is copied **into the debug folder of my unit tests.**

If I do a full rebuild, then the unit test project's appsettings.json file is copied into the debug folder.  **But then when I run a unit test (by pressing ctrl + R + T), the WebAPI project's appsettings.json file is again copied in.**

I assumed that the appsettings.json file copied into the project's debug folder would correspond with the appsettings.json file in that project.  (And it does for a full rebuild.)

**How can I specify which appsettings.json file should be copied to the debug folder of a project's build?**

Comment: It would have been good to include the exact version of Visual Studio that this happened on.  I have run into the same problem with a recent upgrade to Visual Studio 2022.  Looks like it started with an upgrade to version 17.9.0.  I'm currently on 17.9.2, and the problem is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what shenanigans .net core is trying to do by swapping in a different appsetting.json file, but setting my unit test project's appsettings.json file to be an embedded resource made it copy it over.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49778593/16241

Comment: Sadly this didn't help in my case. Did you find any other infos what is going on behind the scenes and why VisualStudio or .Net Core is copying appsetting files from other projects?

Comment: @phifi - Unfortunately this was 4 Years ago.  I don't even recall the problem I was having, much less any research I did at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug listed in the Microsoft Developer Community forum. The workaround specifically sited in this link appears to have worked on VS 2022, version 17.9.2.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/appsettingsjson-not-being-picked-up-in/10584312#T-N10609558

It's not a fix, but at least it gets past the problem.