# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have problems with creating a migration. If I try the following:

```
dotnet-ef migrations add First
```

What it returns:

```
    Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at auth.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_3(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Users\askop\OneDrive\Desktop\auth\Startup.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__10`1.<AddCoreServices>b__10_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider provider)      
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
```

Appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-4BR6O1K\\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=AuthDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "JWT": {
    "ValidAudience": "http://localhost:4200",
    "ValidIssuer": "https://localhost:5100",
    "Secret": "ByYM000OLlMQG6VVVp1OH7Xzyr7gHuw1qvUC5dcGt3SNM"
  }
}
```

My Startup.cs file code for getting the connection string:

```
// For Entity Framework  
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I have tried every article here trying to solve it but none worked. Could someone help me out or had the same issue as me?

Comment: Does your Appsettings.json end up in the output directory ?

Comment: You should set your appsetings.json property to min. Copy if Newer

Comment: I have updated the post with the full output of the terminal is this better?

Comment: What do you mean by setting my appsettings.json property? Could you explain this better.

Comment: right click the appsettings.json file, got to properties, what does the "*Copy to Output Directory" say?

Comment: I'm working in vs code but I don't see the option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ensure that appsettings.dev.json gets copied to the output folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178340/how-can-i-ensure-that-appsettings-dev-json-gets-copied-to-the-output-folder)

Comment: you need add this lines to csproj
`<ItemGroup>
   <None Update="appsettings.json">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>`

Comment: I added the lines but still says the same error.

Comment: Maybe the same that this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64363265/azure-web-deploy-http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure

Comment: You should run the project from the path containing appsetting.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"DefaultConnection": "DESKTOP-4BR6O1K\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=AuthDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"