# Azure web deploy HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4

I have just deployed my .net core and react project on Azure using web deploy and published using Windows instead of Linux. I seem to be getting a HTTP Error 500.30 here are the error logs below, I have used the pre configured identity server 4 when making the application but I assume the error has something to do with this, anyone know of a fix for this?
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7WHY.png)
[Error log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyPQP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that this app works in your development environment, so I think this is a configuration error.

ASP.NET Core have 3 default environments: development, staging and production; and you have differents appsettings for each of them (appsettings.json wich is the base, appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Stating.json and appsettings.Production.json).

My theory is you have the configuration related to IdentityServer only in appsettings.Development.json, so this is not beign loaded in production environment.

Include the configuration in appsettings.json or appsettings.Production.json an check it out.

If you're deploying the app to Azure AppService you could include the config in the AppSettings section.

Check more about config and enviroments:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Hi yes it does work in development, I also have made the app settings in both the production and dev enironment the same when I republished the app but it is still giving me this System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid key type. error.

Comment: Can you share your Startup.cs file and your appsettings.json/appsettings.Production.json, maybe updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem it did have something to do with my appsettings.json where i needed to include     "Key": {
"Type": "Development"
},