# How to publish and deploy an Asp.net Core Database first application with MS SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am publishing a Asp.Net Core app Database first application with MS SQL Server Database. After deploying i am getting SQL Error 26. I tried with the solution mentioned in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865161/asp-net-core-application-not-connecting-to-database-after-publishing/42879878). But here a am getting this error

> 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0' is not a valid name because it contains
>   invalid characters.

Please help

Comment: Is this is your first time deploying in IIS? or your IIS is totally new? Did you register asp.net in your IIS Server?

Comment: Neither i am deploying for first time, nor my IIS is new. This is the first time  i am deploying asp.net core database first application and it is unable to locate server.

Comment: Found answer here
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things need to be checked before deploying asp.net core application in IIS.

1. Application Pool
2. SQL Server
3. Found answer here https://iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler