# Dotnet isn't aware of environment specific appsettings file

Tags: asp.net-core

First of all this question is not same issue with [dotnet publish doesn´t publish correct appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858312/dotnet-publish-doesn%C2%B4t-publish-correct-appsettings-env-environmentname-json) and i am sure there is no problem with name of environment.

> os: linux(ubuntu 14.04)
>
> dotnet --version: 1.0.3

Shell script:

> export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Cloud9
>
> cd ../../src/Project
>
> dotnet restore
>
> dotnet publish -c Debug -o bin/Debug/out/
>
> cp ../../.config/Project /appsettings.Cloud9.json bin/Debug/out/     #copy settings file into publish directory
>
> dotnet bin/Debug/out/Project.dll --urls "http://0.0.0.0:8080"

When i run above script it successfully serves site but with `appsettings.json` values instead of `appsettings.Cloud9.json`.

Here is my `Startup.cs` constructor and `Program.cs`:

```
    //Sturtup.cs
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    //Program.cs
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

A note: if i execute `dotnet run --urls ...` without publish it runs as expected.

Second note: i see `appsettings.Cloud9.json` in the out directory.

Answer (score 1):

Solved after adding `cd ./bin/Debug/out`. So correct script is:

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Cloud9
cd ../../src/Project
dotnet restore
dotnet publish -c Debug -o bin/Debug/out/  
cp ../../.config/Project /appsettings.Cloud9.json bin/Debug/out/
```

Key point:

```
cd ./bin/Debug/out
dotnet Project.dll --urls "http://0.0.0.0:8080"
```