# When using WebDeploy to deploy ASP.NET website to IIS, can I only create appsettings.Production.json if it does not exist?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, webdeploy

My project contains both `appsettings.json` and a default `appsettings.Production.json` files. However an admin may edit the Production file manually on the server and it would get overwritten if I publish it again.

Can I somehow specify **only** this file to not be overwritten if such file already exists?

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37858312/653457) which uses `CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"` does not work because apparently it doesn't work for Web Deploy (IIS Publish) and I want it to not overwrite *even if* the file in the project is newer (i.e. the admin edits it before we modify it in the code).

Comment: Does this work? **Right-Click** --> **Exclude from Project**

Comment: @NickAbbot I didn't test but IFAIK the file would never get published because I have used this before for my local SQLite database files.

Comment: But sometimes you _would_ want it to be overwritten, no? Like if you as a developer make a change to the file locally and want to apply it to production. In light of this, if the file is already being maintained in your source control system, that may be the natural choice as your single source of truth for the file. Then the admins would just need to alert you if they change it on the server.

Comment: @TawabWakil that's true for _some_ of our projects. Some are shared (i.e. a single source code is deployed to multiple different websites) and the difference is that appsettings.

Comment: Your question is: _Can I somehow specify only this file to not be overwritten if such file already exists?_ So, you **deploy it once** and then **exclude from project**.

Comment: @NickAbbot like my previous comment that should work for most of our projects except this one which need to be deployed to multiple websites from the same source code (and in the future if I modify it, I need to deploy them again to all those sites). A modification at Publish profile would be needed I think, like the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude specific files or folders when you build a web package, by creating a custom `.wpp.targets` file in the same folder as your web application project file.

1. Create a custom project file named [project name].wpp.targets in the same folder as your project file.
2. In the .wpp.targets file, add an ItemGroup element.
3. In the ItemGroup element, add ExcludeFromPackageFolders and ExcludeFromPackageFiles items to exclude specific files and folders as required.

The following is the basic structure of this `.wpp.targets` file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>   
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="[semi-colon-separated folder list]">
      <FromTarget>[arbitrary metadata value]</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="[semi-colon-separated file list]">
      <FromTarget>[arbitrary metadata value]</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then you need to add the `.wpp.targets` file to the web application project and use this file to exclude appsettings.json and appsettings.Production.json from the web package when building the project.

For more details, please refer to this document: [Excluding Files and Folders from Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment#excluding-specific-files-and-folders)

Comment: Hi if I read this correctly, this file is tied to the entire build process and not to each publish profile right? That means all deployments will either have the file or not?

Comment: Yes, the .wpp.targets file is relevant to the overall build process and is not specific to individual publish profiles. When you create and include a .wpp.targets file in a web application project, the exclusions specified in the file will apply to all deployment and publish operations for the project. So, if you want to use different exclusions for different publishing profiles, you need to manage these exclusions within the .wpp.targets file itself as per your requirements. This file will become part of the project configuration and will apply to all deployments unless you modify it.